# Angular get method

Tags: angular

I'm Fresher and new to angular. I have one task that I got one get API from the backend. In that API have a bundle of questions. need to display those questions in angular material Form.

here is my Html code

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="example-full-width">
<mat-label *ngFor="let list of data">{{list.question}}</mat-label>
<textarea matInput formControlName="question" value="question"></textarea>
```

here is my ts code

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.data = this.getAllQuestion();
 }

 getAllQuestion() {
this.user.getAllQuestions().subscribe((res: any) => {
  // this.data = this.results.data;
  console.log(res);
})
 }
```

Response structure

```
{
"status": true,
"data": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "questionId": "0c1f5bbd-9732-440a-b74b-61f7f35e4d6d",
        "question": "whats in it for me ?",
        "companyId": "7a8fc735-ac6d-4e1a-9d1d-2b8df54b9033",}
```

where I'm going wrong?
// this.data = this.results.data; if I uncomment this line itshows error thatProperty 'data' does not exist on type 'never[]'.ts(2339)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Make yourself familiar with observables https://angular.io/guide/observables

Comment: it should be `res.data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code:

```
getAllQuestion() {
    this.user.getAllQuestions().subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.data = res.data;
        console.log(res);
    })
}
```

Comment: thanks, Suneet it's working fine. but in response, I have around 16 questions all are displaying in one field. what to do for that

Comment: you can apply ngFor on <mat-form-field> and then every question would have its own <mat-form-field>

Answer (score 1):

Some stuff that is wrong with your code:
`getAllQuestions` is not returning anything, data will not be set to your result.
`this.results.data` does not exist, do you mean `res.data`?

You should use an Observable here to get control over the response.

```
data$: Observable<any>;

ngOnInit(){
    getAllQuestion();
}

getAllQuestion(){
   this.data$ = this.user.getAllQuestions().pipe(map(res => res.data));
}
```

A better way would be to already map the result to your questions in the service, so you don't have to handle that every time you call `getAllQuestions`

Then, in your template, use the async pipe:
`<mat-label *ngFor="let list of data|async">{{list.question}}</mat-label>`

You should make yourself familiar with Observables, Rxjs and so on. Some good sources are:
https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular 
https://www.learnrxjs.io/ 
https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: Thank you @Timon these sources really helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

```
data;

constuctor(user:YourService){}

ngOnInit(){
   this.getAllQuestion();
}

getAllQuestion(){
    this.user.getAllQuestions().subscribe((res: any) => {
    this.data = res.data;
  })
}
```

It would have been nice to see the code snippet for service as well.